# Does different iVar name change retain count when used with property

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Here is 2 code snapshot-

```
@interface A:NSObject
{
     NSMutableArray *a;
}

@property (retain)   NSMutableArray *a;


@implementation

@synthesize a;

-(id)init
{
      if(self=[super init])
     {
            a=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     }
}

@end


@interface A:NSObject
{
     NSMutableArray *_a;

}

@property (retain)   NSMutableArray *a;



@implementation

@synthesize  a=_a;

-(id)init
{
      if(self=[super init])
     {
            _a=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     }
}

@end
```

Now what i need to know, is in both code instance variable  assigned value directly rather than using accessor and retain count is 1? Or there is difference between them. Thanks.

And one more things, apple recommended not to use accessor in  init/dealloc, but at the same time ask not to directly set iVar. So what is the best way to assign value of ivar in init()??

Comment: What is this...  That isn't even actual Objective-C code.

Comment: You should fix your code. It is improperly formatted. Also you ask about the difference between two different code excerpts but you only posted one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ARC vs non-ARC**

First, you should decide whether you want to use automatic reference counting (ARC) or manual reference counting.  It looks like you've chosen the latter - which is fine because you can always transition to ARC later.

**Property attributes/setter semantics**

You have marked the setter semantics for the property `a` as `retain`.  This will work; but since the property is exposed in the class interface, class users may use it to set the `_a` ivar.  Since class users may not expect your class `A` to directly modify the the `NSMutableArray` instance they passed, better to use `copy` semantics for mutable object properties.

**Property access in `init` and `dealloc`**

Use of declared properties in `init` and `dealloc` is often discouraged because doing so may have side effects due to KVO. These side effects may not work well with a partially constructed or partially deconstructed object.

**Your questions**

Here's what I would do:

```
// assumes Xcode 4.4+ for autosynthesize
@interface A:NSObject
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSMutableArray *a;
@end

@implementation A

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if( !self ) return nil;

    _a = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    return self;
}
@end
```

**EDIT:**

Or, if auto synthesize  is not available:

```
@interface A:NSObject
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSMutableArray *a;
@end

@implementation A

@synthesize a = _a;

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if( !self ) return nil;

    _a = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    return self;
}
@end
```

Comment: Hi Alan, thanks for your response. But what would the code if we use  Xcode 4.0 in non-ARC environment??

Comment: "Apple recommends not using properties in intializers and dealloc"- so that means we should use _a rather than self.a ??

Comment: In general, yes.  Can you get away with it if you are certain there are no side effects such as triggering KVO notifications?  Also yes.  In general, I use ivars in the `init` and `dealloc`.  (Actually, I've migrated almost 100% to ARC, so `dealloc` is mostly history.)

Comment: Now another question. what if we have @property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *a;  and then   _a = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init] and
self.a = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init] will both have same retan count??

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in the above two codes mentioned by you. In the latest compiler, you now don't need to specify the instance variable with property. So the above code will now be:

```
@interface A:NSObject
@property (strong) NSMutableArray *a;
@end

@implementation
-(id)init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
       _a = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

In this case, the property "a" is has an automatic synthesize and _a is an instance variable. Basically _ prefixed to property name is instance variable name.

No release if in ARC. Use self.a for accessing anywhere else.

You rightly said that Apple recommends not using properties in intializers and dealloc because their they are not initialized.

And answer to your question: "Does different iVar name change retain count when used with property" is that when using properties, you should not be worried about this. It might have a different retain count for a short period but it should not matter to you or code.

Hope it helps.